# Word order for the sentences begin with "As"

Tags: word-order

I wrote this sentence:

> As/since compared to the number of the nodes, the number of the context nodes and anchors is not considerable, the time complexity is roughly O(N).

Is it grammatical and the order of the clauses correct? Could I make it more natural by relocating some clauses?

Comment: I think you can omit the first "since/as"

Comment: @Cardinal then I should use "*then the time complexity is ...*"

Comment: nop, I mean, "Compared to the X, the numbers ..."

Answer (score 2):

Try to avoid clauses where possible, especially multiple clauses in one sentence. I would suggest:

> As the number of the context nodes and anchors is not considerable
>   **in comparison** to the number of **all** nodes, the time complexity is roughly O(N).

Comment: My last version was *As the number of the context nodes and anchors compared to the number of all nodes is negligible, the time complexity is roughly O(N)*

Comment: Your version is slightly confusing, because it initially reads as _the number of the context nodes and anchors **compared to** the number of all nodes_, meaning those numbers were **comparable**. And suddenly _is negligible_ changes the meaning to the opposite! You either need to separate it by commas, or use the version that I suggested.

Comment: @Aleksey, I think you are right here. Ahmad, I think, would do better to remember he is trying to answer two questions here. The first is "what is the relationship of the "context nodes and anchors" to "all nodes". The 2nd is how that relationship impacts time complexity. (I think.) I believe that using two sentences here would be more understandable. "The number of . . .compared to . . .is minimal / negligible / something.  As a result, the time complexity . . ." Because this appears to be part of a more technical piece of writing, my suggestion may not work. Not sure based on snippet used.